# Why is my Bootstrap 5 NavBar brand aligned all the way left?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Demo</title>

  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-iYQeCzEYFbKjA/T2uDLTpkwGzCiq6soy8tYaI1GyVh/UjpbCx/TYkiZhlZB6+fzT" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark" style="background-color: green;">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My To Do's</a>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" routerLink="">Checklist</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" routerLink="all-tasks">All To Dos</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" routerLink="about">About</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

And when I view it, the nav-brand is munched up against the left.

[image: No padding!]

Am I doing something wrong, or do I  have to do the padding myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is because the `navbar` class, which adds padding, defaults to `0` for "x padding":

```
/* bootstrap.css */
.navbar {
    --bs-navbar-padding-x: 0;
}
```

To fix that, give the variable a value:

```
.navbar {
    /* What the docs use */
    --bs-navbar-padding-x: 0.5rem;
}
```

Comment: Interesting.  Thanks.  Is that a bug or WAD?  Seems weird to me.

Comment: @NickHodges I don't think this would be a bug. 0 seems like a weird default, but that's what they explicitly put into their `bootstrap.css` as the initial value.

Comment: Okay -- fair enough.  Thanks again.